# Why do I get Hash Sum mismatch error when trying to install mono on debian

Tags: debian, aptitude, mono

I am following the [mono installation tutorial](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/getting-started/install/linux/). First I add repo to list, then I import key and finally I try to update the repos.

On last step I get error:

```
W: Failed to fetch http://download.mono-project.com/repo/debian/dists/wheezy/main/binary-amd64/Packages  Hash Sum mismatch

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

I tried to fix this by running `rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*` but the error remains.

Can you help me understand why this error happens and if possible a resolution/workaround? I would prefer not to compile from source nor to use the version in official repository.

I installed debian in a VM using `debian-7.6.0-amd64-DVD-1.iso`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

2 days ago It was working, today I am also having same problem.

But I think hash file is incorrect @ mono-project site.

If you check file size or create hash file for Packages file you can see that it is not same as hash file.

**binaries**

http://origin-download.mono-project.com/repo/debian/dists/wheezy/main/binary-amd64/

**file size and hash list of packages:**

http://origin-download.mono-project.com/repo/debian/dists/wheezy/Release

Edit:
they updated checksum file and also binaries couple of minutes ago and they match now.
Try again, it might work now.

Answer (score 1):

Nesim's answer prompted me to ask on a mono-related mailing list. The answer I got was:

> Wait a few hours. This is caused by the download site being behind a CDN, and the caches for Release and Packages.gz being mismatched. It'll clear itself up within a few hours.

After ~12 hours it has not fixed itself, but a new error arose:

```
W: A error occurred during the signature verification. The repository is not updated and the previous index files will be used. GPG error: http://download.mono-project.com wheezy Release: The following signatures were invalid: BADSIG A6A19B38D3D831EF Xamarin Public Jenkins (auto-signing) <releng@xamarin.com>

W: Failed to fetch http://download.mono-project.com/repo/debian/dists/wheezy/Release

W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

After 14 hours the repository was parsed successfully and the problem has been resolved.

Comment: Mine resolved too but now I am getting: The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 mono-fpm-server : Depends: mono-xsp4-base (>= 3.8) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

Comment: Try to force installation of mono-xsp4-base >= 3.8 first?

Comment: Yep, I tried that, than It gave same error for another monolib, I tried for that this time and problem completely solved.